# SSH Tunnel + Socat UDP + Unicast + Multicast

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, udp, socat

I am trying to communicate from a machine LOCAL (sitting at home) with a scientific instrument (SCIENTIFIC, IP=192.168.1.109) which sits in a remote network along with a raspberry (SERVER).
SCIENTIFIC receives orders on udp port 12109 and answers through udp broadcast on port 12000.

First of all, I can send orders to INSTRUMENT following instructions [here](https://stackpointer.io/network/ssh-port-forwarding-tcp-udp/365/) using TCP-UDP relays.
I first set-up a tunnel SSH from machine LOCAL to SERVER.

```
toto@LOCAL:~$ ssh -L 8001:localhost:8001 Raspberry_ext
```

where Raspberry_ext allows to rebound over several linux machines to get through SERVER.
Then, on SERVER, I launch :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ socat tcp4-listen:8001,reuseaddr,fork udp:192.168.1.109:12109
```

Then on LOCAL :

```
toto@LOCAL:~$ socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:12109,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8001
```

In this way, I can indeed send orders from LOCAL to INSTRUMENT :

```
toto@LOCAL:~$ nc -u localhost 12109 
*IDN?
```

Indeed, on SERVER, I can see the answer without trouble :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nc -u -l 12000
LHLM-137F
```

However, I cannot catch the UDP broadcast from INSTRUMENT and tunnel it back to LOCAL through SERVER. I tried to create another ssh tunnel :

```
toto@LOCAL:~$ ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 Raspberry7_ext
```

But, I do not know exactly how to handle the udp broadcast. I tried among other things:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:12000,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8000
```

But on LOCAL, I do not know how to catch the traffic from port 8000. My naive attemps fails :

```
toto@LOCAL:~$ socat tcp-listen:8000,fork udp:localhost:12000
2020/03/13 00:39:26 socat[10654] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:8000}, 16): Address already in use
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I created a reverse SSH tunnel, and managed to send back UDP packets from port 12000 back through it.

Best,